# FCM Messaging.SharedInstance.FcmToken not set when first registering in my Xamarin.iOS app

Tags: c#, firebase, xamarin.ios, firebase-cloud-messaging

We're using Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.CloudMessaging to get Push Notifications.

It's working fine except for one quirk.

When the app is first installed, `RegisteredForRemoteNotifications` is called, but `Messaging.SharedInstance.Fcmtoken` is not set.

When the app subsequently runs, it *is* set.

We need the FCM token so that we can send it to our back-end server.

How can I get the FCM Token on first installation?

My code is:

```
    public override void RegisteredForRemoteNotifications(UIApplication application, NSData deviceToken)
    {
        // NOTE that the token passed in here is the Apple APNS token.
        // We need the Firebase FCM Token -  this is what is used to manage token sending in Firebase.

        Messaging.SharedInstance.ApnsToken = deviceToken;

        // Why is this empty the first time the app runs?
        var fcmToken = Messaging.SharedInstance.FcmToken;

        Debug.WriteLine($"RegisteredForRemoteNotifications token:'{deviceToken}'");

        // This method can be called with no FCM Token set - so only do something when we've got the token
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(fcmToken))
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"RegisteredForRemoteNotifications fcmtoken:'{Messaging.SharedInstance.FcmToken}'");

            // Subscribe to a 'news' topic so we can send to just those subscribed to this topic
            Messaging.SharedInstance.Subscribe("news");

            // TODO - we will need to send the fcmToken to the back-end server, with the user details, so that the back-end server
            // can then manage notifications and send targetted Notifications to the specific user (e.g. a warning that their policy is expiring soon).
            //SendPushNotificationTokenToTempcoverServer(fcmToken);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to mark the AppDelegate class as an `IMessagingDelegate`. Once this is done, the `DidReceiveRegistrationToken` method is then called, instead of the `RegisteredForRemoteNotifications` method.

This has the FCM token properly populated as the `token` argument.