# Xamarin Forms Firebase push notification can't get token in ios

Tags: ios, firebase, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I implemented push notifications in android work will but in ios token return on null
please any help this log data

```
 2022-11-13 12:34:13.792999+0200 Najd.iOS[14382:119104] [plugin] AddInstanceForFactory: No factory registered for id <CFUUID 0x600000ffaa20> F8BB1C28-BAE8-11D6-9C31-00039315CD46
2022-11-13 12:34:14.241137+0200 Najd.iOS[14382:119122] [general] *** -[NSKeyedUnarchiver validateAllowedClass:forKey:] allowed unarchiving safe plist type ''NSString' (0x7ff863b6d698) [/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework]' for key 'NS.keys', even though it was not explicitly included in the client allowed classes set: '{(
    "'NSDictionary' (0x7ff863b589e0) [/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework]",
    "'NSDate' (0x7ff863b58878) [/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework]"
)}'. This will be disallowed in the future.
 " UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=The server responded with an error. HTTP response: <NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x6000008b2d60> { URL: https://firebaseinstallations.googleapis.com/v1/projects/mana-325311/installations/ } { Status Code: 403, Headers {
    "Alt-Svc" =     (
        "h3=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-29=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q050=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=\":443\"; ma=2592000,quic=\":443\"; ma=2592000; v=\"46,43\""
    );
    "Cache-Control" =     (
        private
    );
    "Content-Encoding" =     (
        gzip
    );
        321
    "Content-Length" =     (
    );
    "Content-Type" =     (
        "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
    );
    Date =     (
        "Sun, 13 Nov 2022 10:35:30 GMT"
    );
    Server =     (
        ESF
    );
    Vary =     (
        Origin,
        "X-Origin",
        Referer
    );
    "x-content-type-options" =     (
        nosniff
    );
    "x-frame-options" =     (
        SAMEORIGIN
    "x-xss-protection" =     (
        0
    );
} }
Response body: {
  "error": {
    );
    "message": "Requests to this API firebaseinstallations.googleapis.com method google.firebase.installations.v1.FirebaseInstallationsService.CreateInstallation are blocked.",
    "code": 403,
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
        "reason": "API_KEY_SERVICE_BLOCKED",
        "domain": "googleapis.com",
        "metadata": {
          "consumer": "projects/509518156709",
          "service": "firebaseinstallations.googleapis.com"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
}
```

I use this plugin to implement firebase **Plugin.FirebasePushNotification** Version 3.4.35
**Xamarin.Forms** Version 5.0.0.2515

this  Code in **AppDelegate**

```
[Register("AppDelegate")]
    public partial class AppDelegate : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.FormsApplicationDelegate
    {
      
        public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
        {
            Xamarin.FormsGoogleMaps.Init("AIzaSyAFh07QpEGWHSecHRTxImrctCZAge0WK5o");
            Xamarin.Forms.Forms.SetFlags("IndicatorView_Experimental");
            Rg.Plugins.Popup.Popup.Init();
            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();
           
            Plugin.LocalNotification.LocalNotificationCenter.RequestNotificationPermission();
            FirebasePushNotificationManager.Initialize(options, true);
   
            LoadApplication(new App());
            return base.FinishedLaunching(app, options);
        }
      
        public override void WillEnterForeground(UIApplication uiApplication)
        {
            Plugin.LocalNotification.LocalNotificationCenter.ResetApplicationIconBadgeNumber(uiApplication);
            //To set for alert
            FirebasePushNotificationManager.CurrentNotificationPresentationOption = UNNotificationPresentationOptions.Alert | UNNotificationPresentationOptions.Sound;

        }

        public override void RegisteredForRemoteNotifications(UIApplication application, NSData deviceToken)
        {
            FirebasePushNotificationManager.DidRegisterRemoteNotifications(deviceToken);
            Messaging.SharedInstance.ApnsToken = deviceToken;
        }

        public override void FailedToRegisterForRemoteNotifications(UIApplication application, NSError error)
        {
            FirebasePushNotificationManager.RemoteNotificationRegistrationFailed(error);

        }
        // To receive notifications in foregroung on iOS 9 and below.
        // To receive notifications in background in any iOS version
        public override void DidReceiveRemoteNotification(UIApplication application, NSDictionary userInfo, Action<UIBackgroundFetchResult> completionHandler)
        {
            // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
            // this callback will not be fired 'till the user taps on the notification launching the application.

            // If you disable method swizzling, you'll need to call this method. 
            // This lets FCM track message delivery and analytics, which is performed
            // automatically with method swizzling enabled.
            FirebasePushNotificationManager.DidReceiveMessage(userInfo);
            // Do your magic to handle the notification data
            System.Console.WriteLine(userInfo);
            //To set for alert
            FirebasePushNotificationManager.CurrentNotificationPresentationOption = UNNotificationPresentationOptions.Alert | UNNotificationPresentationOptions.Sound;

            completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.NewData);
        }
```

Add **GoogleService-Info.plist** file make build action BundleResources

Mark in **Entitlements.plist** push notifications to enable

Mark in **info.plist** Enable BackgroundMode (Remote notification), Add

```
<key>FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled</key>  <false/>
```

in Shared project add this

```
    CrossFirebasePushNotification.Current.OnTokenRefresh += (s, p) =>
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine($"**********TOKEN : {p.Token}");

            if (p.Token != null)
            {
                AppData.Token = p.Token;
                Api.CustomerService.UpdateTokenbynumber();
            }


        };
        // Push message received event
        CrossFirebasePushNotification.Current.OnNotificationReceived += (s, p) =>
        {

            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Received");

            if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.iOS)
            {

                //iOS stuff
                 foreach (var data in p.Data)
                  {
                      var notification = new Plugin.LocalNotification.NotificationRequest
                      {
                          NotificationId = 100,
                          Title = data.Key.ToString(),
                          Description = data.Value.ToString(),
                          ReturningData = "", // Returning data when tapped on notification.
                      };
                    Plugin.LocalNotification.LocalNotificationCenter.Current.Show(notification);
                    //   System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"{data.Key} : {data.Value}");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                var notification = new Plugin.LocalNotification.NotificationRequest
                {
                    NotificationId = 100,
                    Title = p.Data["title"].ToString(),
                    Description = p.Data["body"].ToString(),
                    ReturningData = "", // Returning data when tapped on notification.
                };
                Plugin.LocalNotification.LocalNotificationCenter.Current.Show(notification);
            }
        };
      
        CrossFirebasePushNotification.Current.OnNotificationOpened += (s, p) =>
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Opened");
            foreach (var data in p.Data)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"{data.Key} : {data.Value}");
            }


        };
```

but token return null any help please?

**Entitlements.plist**

```
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>aps-environment</key>
    <string>development</string>
</dict>


</plist>
```

till now i did not find solution any help please?

Comment: Can you try adding a breakpoint to test this line of code to get the Token?
`Messaging.SharedInstance.ApnsToken = deviceToken;`

Comment: Not enter in this function

Comment: You can try this answer to see if it works. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54555090/fcm-messaging-sharedinstance-fcmtoken-not-set-when-first-registering-in-my-xamar#:~:text=The%20solution%20is,the%20token%20argument.

Comment: i update my question, i did not find solutions till now

Comment: Your RegisteredForRemoteNotification method is not called, you can try to check these points: 1. Use a real device for testing, the emulator does not support remote notification. 2. Make sure your certificate is enabled for push notifications. You can refer to the official document: [Push Notifications in iOS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/user-notifications/deprecated/remote-notifications-in-ios)